# The auto formatting for an answer's short link does not work

Tags: bug

If I paste an answer's permalink `https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33497/when-does-the-airline-check-if-an-airplane-can-reach-its-destination/33499#33499` into a post, it automatically changes to:

[When does the airline check if an airplane can reach its destination?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33497/when-does-the-airline-check-if-an-airplane-can-reach-its-destination/33499#33499)

But if I use the short link `https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33499/14897`, it does not.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33499/14897

---

Using the short link for *questions* works fine.

Example:

`https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33497/14897`

becomes

[When does the airline check if an airplane can reach its destination?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33497/14897)

Comment: Is it okay to submit a bug report during an election? As in, will it be seen / forwarded to the correct team?

Comment: [This was reported five years ago on the network-wide meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128330/links-to-answers-are-not-formatted-to-show-the-title-automatically) That site is the correct place for bug reports and discussions that don't just affect the Aviation site.