# How do I link directly to one of several answers?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

How do I link directly to one of several answers?

1. If it is an answer that I am the author of
2. If it is an answer that someone ELSE is the author of-- particularly if it's NOT an answer that I've received a notification about in my inbox.

For example at some point along the way I guess I saw this url in my browser window (see below) but I don't really how it got there or how I would replicate the process of creating it with some other  answer relating to some other question.  Follow the link to see what I mean, you can scroll up or down but you start out positioned with the target answer sitting right there in your browser window.

`https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/which-parts-of-class-e-airspace-can-an-ultralight-part-103-fly-in-without-prio/55714#55714`

Where did "55714" come from and how do I make a link like this for any other given answer that I want to target?  Thanks

[Which parts of class E airspace can an ultralight (part 103) fly in without prior ATC authorization?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/which-parts-of-class-e-airspace-can-an-ultralight-part-103-fly-in-without-prio/55714#55714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the share link below any post (question or answer) and it pops up a box with a link to the post that you can copy and paste.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method in @Ward's answer works. However, it does **not** do the automatic markup for answers (only questions). It is a [known bug / missing feature](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3369/14897).

So what you do is use the short link to go to the page in a different tab, then copy and paste the full URL, this saves you the trouble of doing the markup manually.

Example:

**1. Pasting this:**

`https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/55977/14897`

Will be rendered as:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/55977/14897

**2. But pasting where it goes:**

`https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55976/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-span-wise-false-spar-on-affordaplane-wings/55977#55977`

Will be rendered as:

[What is the purpose of this span wise "false spar" on Affordaplane wings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55976/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-span-wise-false-spar-on-affordaplane-wings/55977#55977)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, partly. Here's one way--

Click on your "reputation" number on upper right of screen.

The screen will change to a display that includes a section entitled "answers".

Click on the "answer" you want to link directly to.  There you go.

But that only works for one of your own answers.

I also see that if I get a "comment" or "answer" notification in my inbox and click on it, that creates a url that will feature that comment or answer at the top of my browser window so that's exactly what I'm trying to do--

But that won't work for some random answer that I've gotten no notification for.